# How to capture user's handwritten signature in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios7

In my app, user will request a digitized, handwritten signature from customers.

I need the ability to capture the signature as the user 'writes' it on the touchscreen. I also need to store an image of the digitized signature for future use.

I need help or pointers to enable my application to have digital signature?

Comment: What is a (or the) digital signature according to your definition?

Comment: Like , we do while signing for home delivery. It can be using fingers or digital pen whatever is possible option in iOS.

Comment: You're really just talking about plain old signature accepted on a touch screen. The term *digital signature* usually means [something quite different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). You might want to edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: I have done this in the past by catching the touches events and then adding the points to a UIBezierPath, then you can just draw that BezierPath in your view.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you're really talking about recording a user's "analog" signature on an iOS device, all you need to do is to create an image as the user moves a finger or stylus around a view. There are a number of tutorials on the web that illustrate that (here's [one from Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit)).

The basic idea is to build up a path by adding points as you track a touch in a view. When the user is done, you can save the resulting image itself or just save the path or paths. So, you'll probably create a subclass of `UIView` called something like `SignatureView`, and you'll implement the touch-related responder methods `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `-touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `-touchesCancelled:withEvent:`. When a touch begins, you'll create a new bezier path. Each time the touch moves, add a point to that path. When the touch ends, add the new path to the list of paths that the view has recorded. You'll probably also want a method to erase the view by clearing the path list, as well as a `-drawRect:` method to draw the paths and some way for the view controller to retrieve the paths or image.

Also, it should go without saying that you need to be extremely careful about what you do with a user's signature. Avoid storing unencrypted images of the signature, and perhaps avoid storing the signature on the device at all. You could instead send the signature to a server where it might be easier to protect.

Comment: Yes,i will not store signature on the device , will be sending the image to server and store at secured server.

Comment: Is this record of (bezier) points enough for handwritten signature? Shouldn't be there record of speed, velocity, pressure and angle somewhere?

Answer (score 13):

I guess these following links could help you!
Anyway I found those while I's in search for the same purpose in the internet!
Hope this works out for all of us!

The following links are regarding the same resource:
Capturing handwritten Signature on iOS Devices.

1. https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/capture-a-signature-on-ios
2. https://github.com/jharwig/PPSSignatureView
3. http://java.dzone.com/articles/capture-signature-ios
4. http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit

**Note:**
As of today(13-Nov-2015), I noticed that the first link provided above from (altamiracorp.com) is not available for some unknown reason, may be they have put down their website. So I thought to publicly share one of my copies I have saved in EverNote, as it has some educational value theory wise. [So please kindly access it here](https://www.evernote.com/l/APka55vW_ahAV5CfI4d5lDLLidVX4m-LAFY).

Guess this answer helped you! :) (Y)

Comment: how do we clear and save the signature using `PPSSignatureView`?, i have implemented that. And also the first link is not working anymore.

Comment: Use this library: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftSignatureView

Answer (score 5):

Please use **apple research kit** (http://www.apple.com/in/researchkit/)

See more details:

https://github.com/researchkit/researchkit

ViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <ResearchKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate> // Delegate

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *signImageview;
    @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) ORKConsentDocument *consentDocument;
    @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) ORKConsentSignature *signature;
```

ViewController.m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        _consentDocument = [[ORKConsentDocument alloc] init];
        _signature = [[ORKConsentSignature alloc] init];
        ORKConsentReviewStep *signatureStep = [[ORKConsentReviewStep alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"sign" signature:_signature inDocument:_consentDocument];

        ORKOrderedTask *task =
        [[ORKOrderedTask alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"task" steps:@[signatureStep]];

        ORKTaskViewController *taskViewController =  [[ORKTaskViewController alloc] initWithTask:task taskRunUUID:nil];
        taskViewController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:taskViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    #pragma mark - ORKTaskViewController delegate method

    - (void)taskViewController:(ORKTaskViewController *)taskViewController
           didFinishWithReason:(ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason)reason
                         error:(NSError *)error {

        ORKConsentDocument *documentCopy = [_consentDocument copy];

        ORKConsentSignatureResult *signatureResult =
        (ORKConsentSignatureResult *)[[[taskViewController result] stepResultForStepIdentifier:@"sign"] firstResult];
        [signatureResult applyToDocument:documentCopy];

        self.signImageview.image = signatureResult.signature.signatureImage;

        // Then, dismiss the task view controller.
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a version of this in swift?

Comment: Designed the library that you capture the user signature with name and date and supports both Objective-C and Swift languages.

https://github.com/vigneshuvi/iOS-Signature-Capture

Comment: I have a requirement to capture a signature, but it's not a medical app.  Do Apple allow use of the ResearchKit for non-medical apps?

Comment: Yeah, Apple will allow.