# User signature on app screen

Tags: ios, swift

How to capture user signature on our app screen?

How to achieve it, any ideas please?

Is it possible with UIImageView?

Comment: There is already lots of stuff available regarding this. First try to search on google before ask otherwise question will be consider as replicated.Hope you understand. Now take ref - > [Stack-ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241881/how-to-capture-users-handwritten-signature-in-ios-app) and [Cocoa-control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ios-signature-capture)

Comment: Do you mean a box where the user can 'write' their signature, which you can save a re-use?

Comment: @SteveIves Yes exactly. I want to save this image on Server side and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

`ResearchKit` has this functionality built-in and it's open-source. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/104575/researchkit-tutorial-with-swift) that shows you how to build a simple app with a Consent collecting a signature at the end.